# Key bindings does not run

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, key-bindings, keystroke

I work java program language in netbeans. I want to move a jlabel box by means of use keybindings. Box can not move when ı keystroked. For example I keystroke w,a,s,d but box cannot move. When I press these keys, it should go up, down, right and left, but there is no movement in the program. The box stays where it is. What should do ı?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class BoxGame {

JFrame frame;
JLabel label;
Action upAction;
Action downAction;
Action leftAction;
Action rightAction;


BoxGame(){
    
   frame = new JFrame("Keybinding");
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   frame.setSize(450,450);
   frame.setLayout(null);
   
   label = new JLabel();
   label.setBackground(Color.red);
   label.setBounds(100,100,100,100);
   label.setOpaque(true);
  
   
   upAction = new UpAction();
   downAction = new DownAction();
   leftAction = new LeftAction();
   rightAction = new RightAction();
   
   label.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("w"), "upAction");
   label.getActionMap().put("upAction",upAction);
   
   label.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("s"), "downAction");
   label.getActionMap().put("downAction", downAction);
   
   label.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("a"), "leftAction");
   label.getActionMap().put("leftAction", leftAction);
   
   label.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("d"), "rightAction");
   label.getActionMap().put("rightAction", rightAction);
   
   frame.add(label);
   frame.setVisible(true);

}

public class UpAction extends AbstractAction{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        label.setLocation(label.getX(), label.getY()-10);
    }
}

public class DownAction extends  AbstractAction{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       label.setLocation(label.getX(), label.getY()+10);
    }
}

public class LeftAction extends AbstractAction{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       label.setLocation(label.getX()-10, label.getY());
    }
}

public class RightAction extends AbstractAction{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      label.setLocation(label.getX()+10, label.getY());
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: You are using the wrong InputMap. Your label doesn't have focus. You need to use the `InputMap` that allows you to handle the key binding even when the component doesn't have focus. Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How Key Bindings Work](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#maps) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Start by making use of a more "gloabl" `InputMap`, the one you are using requires the component to be focusable AND have focus.

Avoid using `KeyEvent.getKeyStroke(String)`, it does some weird things and isn't going to help you, instead, supply the actual `KeyEvent`, for example

```
InputMap inputMap = label.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0), "upAction");
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0), "downAction");
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0), "leftAction");
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0), "rightAction");
```

I'd also recommend making the time to learn about custom painting, as components don't tend to work well like this.

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more details